# Removing bottom border from Yelp site badge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been attempting to remove the bottom border from a Yelp site badge that appears (most clearly) when using Firefox.

```css
<style> div.yelp-biz-badge-script-plain-j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w a {
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="yelp-biz-badge-plain-j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w"><a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/weyhrauch-law-group-llp-richland">Check out Weyhrauch Law Group, LLP on Yelp</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, t) {
      var g = d.createElement(t);
      var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      g.id = "yelp-biz-badge-script-plain-j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w";
      g.src = "//dyn.yelpcdn.com/biz_badge_js/en_US/plain/j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w.js";
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    }(document, 'script'));
  </script>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That button is an image. Not CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little easier when you understand the actual output HTML

```
<div id="yelp-biz-badge-plain-j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w">

<a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/weyhrauch-law-group-llp-kennewick-2">

<img alt="Weyhrauch Law Group, LLP" src="https://dyn.yelpcdn.com/extimg/genericYelpBizButton.png" height="33" width="88">

</a>

</div>
```

The anchor link has this CSS

```
a {
  color: #003f72;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #003f72; /* did you want this? */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

..and this is the image

[image]

So this

```
#yelp-biz-badge-plain-j3i0uapgqgIpKNS9KA2v4w a {
border:none;
}
```

should do the trick

**Quite simply, based on your edited question you were using a class selector instead of the ID.**

Comment: Hmm, yes, tried that.  It's still appearing under the image?